# Can I set image for send and cancel button on MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I know it is possible to set the navbar item image on a MFMailComposer as my navigationbar image now(red seen is my  image).I want to use custom images for the backgrounds of the buttons.

[image]

it's my app requirement..

[image]

Comment: I've not discovered a way to influence the layout of the MFMailComposer screen.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Does UIAppearance carry through to the mail composer? Have you already managed to alter the appearance of the navigation bar as shown in your image?

Comment: You can edit the tint color the navigationbar, and even add a custom image to it, but you can not push your own buttons to the MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

While you allocate the `MFMailComposeViewController`, do as follows.

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:182/255.0 green:39.0/255 blue:51.0/255 alpha:0.9];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

From Apple doc [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html),

> Important The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

Comment: i use it above code but it is change my button color,But my requirement  is set image on button.

Comment: That `UIBarButtonItem` is created by code or through nib file?

Comment: but how to give code for send and cancel button for MFMailComposer

Comment: No, we cannot customize the `MFMailComposeViewController`. Only we can set tintColor to the navigationBar.

Comment: Oh..ok,Therefore can i send mail with out MFMailComposeViewController.if yes then tell me what is the process.